# Filling a 2D array with lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I've tried to fill a 2D array with a bunch of lists. I know that I could treat it as a 3D array, and access the data quite the same, but for my purpose I really would prefer treating it as a 2D array with lists as elements instead of numbers.

One variant of the Code I've tried:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.empty([2, 2])
b = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]

a[0][0] = b[0]

print a[0][0]
```

I understand why it doesn't work that way, and that it would work using a 3D array.

In C I would fill that 2D array with pointers to the data I want to fill in, but I don't know how to do a similar thing in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the type of the array to `dtype=object`:

```
a = np.empty([2, 2],dtype=object)
```

So now we have a 2d array of references, all set to `None`, like:

```
>>> np.empty([2, 2],dtype=object)
array([[None, None],
       [None, None]], dtype=object)
```

Next we can assign an object to an element:

```
>>> a[0][0] = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
>>> a
array([[list([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]), None],
       [None, None]], dtype=object)
```

Mind that for numpy, these objects are blackboxes. So you cannot for instance construct a 3d matrix by using several assignment statements, and then calculate something as if it is a 3d matrix.

Comment: It's fine that numpy treats these as blackboxes, for my usecase thats desired behavior.